# How do I combine two arrays without repeating values?

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
array('1','2','3','4');
array('4','5','6','7');
```

Based on them, I'd like to generate an array that contains only unique values:

```
array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7');
```

Is there any suitable function for this in PHP?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use [`array_merge`](http://php.net/array_merge) for this and then [`array_unique`](http://php.net/array_unique) to remove duplicate entries.

```
$a = array('1','2','3','4');
$b = array('4','5','6','7');

$c = array_merge($a,$b);

var_dump(array_unique($c));
```

Will result in this:

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "3"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "4"
  [5]=>
  string(1) "5"
  [6]=>
  string(1) "6"
  [7]=>
  string(1) "7"
}
```

Comment: You might also want to [`sort`](http://uk.php.net/sort) that to get the list he has, though odd example with string numbers, lexical vs numerical sort considerations.

Answer (score 8):

Yes it is [array_merge()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) to remove dups [array_unique()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

```
array_unique( array_merge( $array1, array2 ) );
```

Comment: That will leave duplicate entries.

Comment: @Felix - YES - need to go with array_unique() - speed, speed, speed