# How to remove common elements in php arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I array like

```
$var1 = [3,4,5,6];

$var2 = [5,6,7,8]
```

Now i want the new array with elements not repeated like

```
$var3 = [3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I combine two arrays without repeating values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686158/how-do-i-combine-two-arrays-without-repeating-values)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`array_unique` removes duplicate values from an array

Answer (score 4):

```
array_unique(array_merge($arr1, $arr2))
```

Answer (score 3):

`$newarray = array_unique(array_merge($oldarray1, $oldarray2));`

Answer (score 1):

Try using [**array_unique**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) and [**array_merge**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php). This should help you.

Answer (score 1):

Plz refer to the manual [array_merge()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) and [array_unique()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
$var3 = array_unique(array_merge($var1, $var2), SORT_NUMERIC);
```